# Retrieve namespace list from file and add to XSL file

Tags: xslt

My XSL starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="x.abc.com/xjd"
      xmlns:x="x.abc.com/x"
      xmlns:p="x.abc.com/x/p"
      xmlns:c="x.abc.com/x/c">
```

The namespace definitions are hardcoded.  I'd like to create a file that had just the namespace definitions and add it to the XSL document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way namespaces inherit, you really can't do that easily with normal XSLT mechanisms, even using XSLT's importing capability. The best suggestion I've got for you would be to make a copy of the stylesheet, programmatically alter the namespace bindings, and run that copy. That could be done, if desired, by using a stylesheet that processes this stylesheet as input.

However, this looks to me like an X/Y question: you seem to be jumping to a particular (awkward) solution to another problem, and I'm not convinced that this *is* the right answer for what you actually want to do. I honestly can't think of a legitimate problem that can be solved by changing namespaces but nothing else in the stylesheet. What's the actual task you're trying to perform?

Comment: The thinking was to not have anything hard-coded in the stylesheet.  My example only showed 4 namespaces but the real document has closer to 30.  We were thinking to have a separate file that only contains the namespaces and could be altered separately from the stylesheet.  It seems like it would be overly complicated - think I'll just keep it in the stylesheet.

Comment: Modularizing just the namespaces really isn't significantly useful. Any document where the namespaces change is also going to change element names, attribute names, document structure, or other things which will require either stylesheet redesign or much more modularizing than just the namespaces.